# Strange error on running pigunit sample test

Tags: java, apache-pig

I'm trying to setup the pig unit tests and I was looking into the documentation which they've provided. It seems a bit outdated so I switched to the svn trunk. The first strange thing is that actually it needs some more libs, not only pigunit, pig and hadoop-commons in order to work(add hadoop-hdfs, hadoop-mapreduce-client-core, hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient). I'm not sure that having these in my dependency manager is something good but this is not the main problem. So here's the test I'm trying to execute:

```
 @Test
public void testNtoN() throws ParseException, IOException {
    String[] args = {
                    "n=3",
                    "reducers=1",
                    "input=top_queries_input_data.txt",
                    "output=top_3_queries",
    };
    test = new PigTest("script dir", args);

    String[] output = {
                    "(yahoo,25)",
                    "(facebook,15)",
                    "(twitter,7)",
    };

    test.assertOutput("queries_limit", output);
}
```

And here's the actual script:

```
 data =
     LOAD '$input'
     AS (query:CHARARRAY, count:INT);

 queries_group = 
     GROUP data 
     BY query
     PARALLEL $reducers;

 queries_sum = 
     FOREACH queries_group 
     GENERATE 
         group AS query, 
         SUM(data.count) AS count;

 queries_ordered = 
     ORDER queries_sum 
     BY count DESC
     PARALLEL $reducers;

 queries_limit = LIMIT queries_ordered $n;

 STORE queries_limit INTO '$output';
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
 STORE queries_limit INTO 'top_3_queries';
 --> none

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias queries_limit

 at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:1019)
 at org.apache.pig.pigunit.PigTest.getAliasFromCache(PigTest.java:224)
 at org.apache.pig.pigunit.PigTest.getActualResults(PigTest.java:319)
 at org.apache.pig.pigunit.PigTest.assertOutput(PigTest.java:409)
 at org.apache.pig.pigunit.PigTest.assertOutput(PigTest.java:400)
 at BlaUnitTest.testBla(BlaUnitTest.java:24)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
 at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
 at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't retrieve job.
 at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:1083)
 at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:994)
 ... 34 more
```

I tried to debug it to see what actually happens and this occurs when it tries to build the query plan and acquire the ExecJob but I couldn't figure it out. I even tried to simplify the script and remove everything but the code for loading and storing the data. The result was the same.

Comment: Pig reads using PigStorage by default and \t is the default delimiter that is used. Are you sure top_queries_input_data.txt is delimited accordingly? WRT your question on including hadoop-mapreduce-* libraries, you could include them only for tests. If you're using gradle for dependency mgmt, you can use testCompile. I'm sure there is a way to do similar in maven and other in dependency mgmt.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the exact data in their svn(http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/test/data/pigunit/). And I assume that the problem might be related to some configurations of the PigServer(I'm running it in LOCAL mode, but it might have some additional configs) or it can be OS related(I'm using Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Is it giving you any stacktrace that can help narrowing down the issue? Also, this is all in memory so I doubt if any configuration is needed

Comment: try to add `dump` after each query - you will find out which one is the problematic since pig is lazy

Comment: I tried to dump the first var(dump data) and it threw the same error there- "Unable to open iterator for alias data". So I'm starting to think that it should be some configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded to resolve the issue. The problem was that I had included some dependencies in the classpath which seems to mess up the correct execution. The only needed dependencies are hadoop-core(I'm using hadoop-aws because I'm using it with aws), hadoop-client, pig and pigunit. So now everything is running correctly.